# Can you create a class structure that does not have Object as its base class

Tags: java, object, jvm

As far as a I know: Every class in Java inherits the methods of the Object Class without the need of specifying to do so, which makes this class so unique and interesting.

Thus I wonder, where is this "rule" specified, inside the JVM? Can this class be somehow manipulated, for example adding or removing a method or variable? Is it possible to create a parallel, hierarchical structure independently of the Object class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to create a class which does not derive directly or indirectly from `java.lang.Object` you must create a class file which does not have a [superclass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#File_layout_and_structure) specified.

Now if you look at the JDK code which parses a class file you will find that the class file parser does this [check](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u-dev/hotspot/file/bd8f2377a415/src/share/vm/classfile/classFileParser.cpp#l3148):

```
if (super_class_index == 0) {
  check_property(class_name == vmSymbols::java_lang_Object(),
                 "Invalid superclass index %u in class file %s",
                 super_class_index,
                 CHECK_(nullHandle));
} else {
```

so it would reject your base class. Only `java.lang.Object` can have no superclass.

Comment: Wow, this opened a whole new field on how I look at Java. I see there are still many many new things to learn.. this is so interesting.

Answer (score 11):

The `Object` class itself is indeed special. If you take a look at it's implementation in `rt.jar` in your jre folder, you will notice most of it's methods are just declarations with a `native` modifier.

```
package java.lang;

public class Object
{
  private static native void registerNatives();

  public final native Class<?> getClass();

  public native int hashCode();

  public boolean equals(Object paramObject)
  {
    return this == paramObject;
  }

  protected native Object clone()
    throws CloneNotSupportedException;

  public String toString()
  {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
  }

  public final native void notify();

  public final native void notifyAll();

  public final native void wait(long paramLong)
    throws InterruptedException;

  public final void wait(long paramLong, int paramInt)
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    if (paramLong < 0L) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }
    if ((paramInt < 0) || (paramInt > 999999)) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("nanosecond timeout value out of range");
    }
    if (paramInt > 0) {
      paramLong += 1L;
    }
    wait(paramLong);
  }

  public final void wait()
    throws InterruptedException
  {
    wait(0L);
  }

  protected void finalize()
    throws Throwable
  {}

  static {}
}
```

Those native methods are implemented inside the JVM itself. These methods are the bridge between the native and managed parts of a Java program. Because of this, it is natural to have this `Object` class as "the common things in every object". The Java language is specified in a way that there is no way to build a separate class hierarchy besides `Object`.

#### About modifying `Object`

Although I haven't tried it yet, it *might* be possible to modify the original Object class. It's sure that the existing methods cannot be removed, because most of the runtime relies on them, but I see a chance you can add new methods by modifying the runtime itself.

It seems you cannot use [java agents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) to modify the `Object`, `String`, `ClassLoader`, `Class<?>`, `ProtectionDomain`, `IllegalClassFormatException`, and array classes.

Comment: If `Object` is the only object which doesn't inherit from another object, how can `Object` be implemented natively in Java?

Comment: @tac See wero's great answer, I think that answers this question

Answer (score 8):

The rule is specified in the [JLS, Section 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4):

> [T]he direct superclass of the class type C is the type given in the extends clause of the declaration of C if an extends clause is present, or Object otherwise.

Every class is either a direct subclass of `Object`, either by not providing an `extends` clause or by explicitly extending `Object`, or an indirect subclass of `Object`, by explicitly extending another subclass of `Object`.

Because of this, a class in this class hierarchy must either directly or indirectly extend `Object`; there can be no other object hierarchies that are independent of `Object`.

Answer (score 4):

The Java object class is a superclass for all the classes you declare.

According to Oracle :

> The Object class, in the java.lang package, sits at the top of the
>   class hierarchy tree. Every class is a descendant, direct or indirect,
>   of the Object class. Every class you use or write inherits the
>   instance methods of Object. You need not use any of these methods,
>   but, if you choose to do so, you may need to override them with code
>   that is specific to your class.

Methods in the Object class can be overriden to suit your needs.

For example : Overriding `equals()` and `hashcode()` in POJOs is a common practice.

You should also look at [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to find out how to modify an Object's behavior at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. where is this "rule" specified, inside the JVM ?

Its not done by the JVM. The compiler adds `extends Object` to your class.

> 2. Can this class be somehow manipulated

NO

> 3. Is it possible to create a parallel, hierarchical structure independently of the Object class?

No. you cant. Each and every java class will extend `Object` class anyway and you just cant avoid it